# Bat file works on C drive to delete registry, but it doesn't delete them when run on network drive

Tags: batch-file

I have a .bat file that deletes the login username from Windows 10, so when they log off their name won't appear. I did it by changing the registry:

It works when I run it from my C drive, but it doesn't delete the registry when I run it from my network drive called U from the server.

```
 echo Resetting last logged on username.
 set id = example
 %SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe DELETE HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI /v LastLoggedOnUserSID /f
 %SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe DELETE HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI /v LastLoggedOnDisplayName /f
 echo y|%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe ADD HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI /v LastLoggedOnUser /d %id% /f
 echo y|%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe ADD HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI /v LastLoggedOnSAMUser /d %id% /f
 PAUSE
```

Comment: How did you run it from the server? Also, there's a setting you can set by Group Policy which tells Windows not to show the previous session's username. This would be the correct way to accomplish what you're trying here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/interactive-logon-do-not-display-last-user-name

Comment: What I meant with run it from the server is that I ran it from my network drive. I can't change the policy because we want the users to have their username in their computers, but as a tech I have to go to their computers to help them but sometimes they lock my account by trying to login thinking they are in their account.

Comment: What error(s) or ouput do you get when you run this from the network drive? Have you tried using PowerShell to do this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/working-with-registry-keys?view=powershell-6

Comment: Try using the UNC path location to the file so with its full UNC path and file name and see if that helps any. So use something like ... `\\servername\sharename\folder\script.bat`